# Will Instagram serve square thumbnails for portrait/landscape images?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

We have a custom Instagram integration in our site, the design for which assumes (and currently depends upon) the images it displays being square.

Instagram announced today that they will support landscape and portrait photos.  Is there a way to load only square images/thumbnails even if the Instagram image is portrait/landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hack for getting square images that I am using:

You take the thumbnail url which includes the correct cropping command and then replace the 150x150 with the size you actually want the image at.

For example, an api response for a landscape image thumbnail:

```
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c135.0.810.810/11909312_160908554245117_2021517224_n.jpg",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150
    }
```

the part `c135.0.810.810` is doing the cropping to a square, which we want to keep, but the `s150x150` is too small so replacing that with `s640x640` gives us our cropped square image at the required size.

You can play around with the cropping command if you want this changed - e.g. setting the first number to `0` will give you a left-aligned cropped image.

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far, thanks!  There are some scenarios where it doesn't work. For instance: https://instagram.com/p/65PhxOs_RH/
.
I think it's because the image/video is too small at it's shortest axis.  So this hack works for displaying square images so long as the image you're trying to use meets a certain minimum size.

Comment: Can we find a new workaround, starting Jan 10th 2018, all my sites instagram feed script stopped working using this method...... the image will return a "Invalid URL signature" adding 640 has no effect, and now it seems I will be forced to us the thumbnails at 150, and the quality is way to low to want to use this.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes** it does.

I just spent some time poking around, and found some interesting things.

**Short Answer:** The API is still returning the square versions for images, even the ones that are uploaded as Portraits or Landscapes. If you want the original landscape / portrait images also, you have to do a little hack -- details below -- until they address it in their API response).

Ex: See this one photo of Taylor Swift uploaded by 1 of the user's mentioned in IG's blog post / press release -- @johnbenett

https://instagram.com/p/6ZVIHTJLYg/

This is the original uploaded photo - Portrait **512 px** x **640 px**

[image]

And here's what the Instagram API returns, for the various images (including thumbnail) for the above portrait image.

```
  "images": {
    "low_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 320
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150
    },
    "standard_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 640
    }
```

So the standard resolution image returned by the API for this Portrait image is **640 px square** and looks like this.

[image]

and the low resolution image returned by the API for this Portrait image is **320 px square** and looks like this.

[image]

and last but not least, the thumbnail image returned by the API for this Portrait image is **150 px square** and looks like this.

[image]

Notice how the photo has been cropped top and bottom to make it 640 square. If this is what you are looking for, then you are good to go, and you may stop reading right here :)

### Further reading

If you want the original portrait / landscape images also, then read on. Videos also evaluated at the end.

#### How do I get the original image for a photo uploaded as a landscape or portrait?

Since the API returns only 1 set of images as of now, but the site is able to show the original aspect ratio images, I did some digging around, and realized that if you remove the `/c0.135.1080.1080` from the urls of the square images, you get to the original aspect ratio sized UNCROPPED images.

Keeping the same example above:

**Square Cropped Image URL (returned by API)**
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg

**Portrait Image URL (arrived at by modifying Square Image URL)**
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg

Hope this helps.

I am guessing they will eventually update the API to return the Square images and the landscape, portrait images for image media type.

#### What about Videos?

I checked out Videos posted as landscape or portrait. For these, the `videos` array has the videos in the original aspect ratio, while the `images array` has square versions of the video `Poster` / Thumbnail images.

Example: Here's a landscape video: https://instagram.com/p/65WW2uzO2f/?taken-by=schwa23

[image]

The API returns landscape resolution for the video files:

```
  "videos": {
    "low_bandwidth": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11912667_1635209236718259_43009002_s.mp4",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 599
    },
    "standard_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11912667_1696545230566321_1671523019_n.mp4",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 799
    },
    "low_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11912667_1635209236718259_43009002_s.mp4",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 599
    }
  }
```

and square images for the video poster image / cover image.

```
  "images": {
    "low_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e15/11856717_420039798193500_1047568791_n.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 320
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e15/c140.0.360.360/11848988_1472118453090746_1196959304_n.jpg",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150
    },
    "standard_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/e15/11856717_420039798193500_1047568791_n.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 640
    }
```

So with Videos, you are good to go, since the `images` array has the square images and the `videos` array has the actual videos in original aspect ratio.

Comment: This image looks different: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11931019_1008201245898476_727940725_n.jpg

Comment: Hey @PedroCasado What do you mean by "looks different" ?

Comment: Do I understand right that: portrait photos are cropped to squares, but landscape photos get white bars attached up and down? Kind of inconsistent to me. I was expecting to see the landscape photos cropped to center square too.

Comment: @shiva, your answer is very thorough as far as portrait images. However my experimenting is showing very different results for landscape images and videos.  From what I can tell so far, Instagram **does** serve cropped square images for _portrait_ Instagrams, but **does not** serve cropped square images for _landscape_ Instagrams.  This is very strange so far...

Comment: @DrewMcDowell Thanks. can you post an example link that I can check out.

Comment: Here's a landscape version that does not work, as @DrewMcDowell said: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11909381_778261432286393_1061732726_n.jpg

Comment: tl;dr, this technique (for now) only works for portrait photos, not landscape.

Comment: @ArxPoetica Not 100% true, but you are right, API is behaving inconsistently, so hack is not advisable for automated programs. Here are the landscape urls for Drew's images - Full Landscape versions, uncropped.
Thumbnail: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg
Low Res: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg
Standard Res: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg

Comment: My concern is after June 1, 2016, cause Instagram explicit says on their API that the square photos will be no longer available. Only for thumbnails (150x150). That sucks. I have a perfect (and simple) square grid on my site made from low_resolution versions and it seems it will be broken after migration (or very poor quality if a have to change to thumbnails). Does anyone have info about this? Why Instagram is going to deprecate something that works despite adding another two versions of image?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell so far, everything works as normal but the thumbnail won't be cropped in like on the Instagram app, you will see the white borders.

There must be a couple of extra image urls we can access but I haven't seen any update in the api docs.

Answer (score 0):

Update. Instagram just announced API support for landscape/portrait photo.
[Blog post](http://developers.instagram.com/post/128288227716/api-migration-for-landscape-and-portrait-formats)

> **By default, the setting is disabled** and the API will continue to return media in the old square format. When enabled, the API will return media in the format it was actually shared, which may be non-square. The ‘thumbnail’ images will not be affected by this setting, and they will continue to be square.

You don't have to change anything now but from **June 1, 2016**  all clients will receive photos and videos only in the format it was actually shared.

For my integration I want to receive original images so I enabled a new setting called Migrations in the “Edit Client” dashboard ( Instagram dev app configuration ).

I did some tests and it works fine. Here is example object returned by Instagram API:

```
{
    'low_resolution': Image: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/e35/p320x320/11849291_1520473841577439_1881145227_n.jpg,
    'standard_resolution': Image: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/11849291_1520473841577439_1881145227_n.jpg,
    'thumbnail': Image: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11849291_1520473841577439_1881145227_n.jpg
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine"? The question is will the Instagram API serve square images for portrait/landscape Instagrams.  The blog post seems to indicate that the default is to continue serving square images, however that doesn't always seem to be the case.  Of the URLs you posted above, only the thumbnail is square.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I misinterpreted this topic. Content edited.