# Instagram Square photos API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Will Instagram provide any way to grab the portrait/landscape through the API ? API docs looks untouched.

As of now, they still returns the square sizes for the portrait images, but the api documentation doesn't provide any way to get the original image.

Will they keep returning the square images? Do Instagram have any comments about this?

Comment: You should probably contact Instagram for an answer.

Comment: @DanielStorm, they recommend to use StackOverflow for these questions. "The Stack Overflow community is a great place to ask API related questions or if you need help with your code. Make sure to tag your questions with the Instagram tag to get fast answers from other fellow developers." https://instagram.com/developer/support/

Comment: I'm saying you should contact Instagram directly because no one can answer this question. Your guess is as good as mine and anyone else's on Stack Overflow. Instagram is the only one that knows what Instagram is going to do in the future.

Comment: @PedroCasado Check out my updated answer. Instagram has put out a new setting on API Client that will now return the rectangular (for Portraits, Landscapes) images.

Comment: @Shiva great! they finally added some documentation about this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Sept. 4th 2015 Update:

As of Sept. 3rd 2015, [instagram now allows API clients to get the images in their original aspect ratio](http://developers.instagram.com/post/128288227716/api-migration-for-landscape-and-portrait-formats) (i.e. rectangular for Landscapes, Portraits) and will not crop them, if you updated a new setting in the API Client.

#### Steps:

1. Login to  into your client application settings on https://instagram.com/developer/
2. Click **Manage Clients** on top nav menu.
3. Locate your API Client, and click **Edit**.
4. Click the **Migrations** Tab for your API Client application, and check the box that says "Non square media".
5. Click **Update Client**.

[image]

That's it! Now when you get the images from the API endpoints, the portraits, landscapes that were uploaded will not be cropped to square images, and the originals will be returned.

Related Blog Post: [API migration for landscape and portrait formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260806/325521)

#### Previous Answer (Deprecated, do not use unless you want BOTH square and non-square versions, still hacky :) )

Yes, the API looks untouched, but I found a hack to get to the original images for Landscapes and Portraits. You have to programatically remove a section of the urls returned in the `images` array.

See below -- snippet from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32260806/325521).

The API is still returning the square versions for images, even the ones that are uploaded as Portraits or Landscapes. If you want the original landscape / portrait images also, you have to do a little hack -- details below -- until they address it in their API response.

#### Let's take an example and walk through it.

See this one photo of Taylor Swift uploaded by 1 of the user's mentioned in [IG's blog post / press release](http://blog.instagram.com/post/127722429412/150827-portrait-and-landscape) -- [@johnbenett](https://instagram.com/johnbarnett/)

https://instagram.com/p/6ZVIHTJLYg/

This is the original uploaded photo - Portrait **512 px** x **640 px**

[image]

And here's what the Instagram API returns, for the various images (including thumbnail) for the above portrait image.

```
  "images": {
    "low_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 320
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
      "width": 150,
      "height": 150
    },
    "standard_resolution": {
      "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 640
    }
```

So the standard resolution image returned by the API for this Portrait image is **640 px square** and looks like this.

[image]

and the low resolution image returned by the API for this Portrait image is **320 px square** and looks like this.

[image]

and last but not least, the thumbnail image returned by the API for this Portrait image is **150 px square** and looks like this.

[image]

#### So How do you get the original image for a photo uploaded as a landscape or portrait?

Since the API returns only 1 set of images as of now, but the site is able to show the original aspect ratio images, I did some digging around, and realized that if you remove the last but 1 section of the url from the square image urls (in this example, remove `/c0.135.1080.1080` ) you get to the original aspect ratio sized (and uncropped) landscape, portrait images.

Keeping the same example above:

**Standard Resolution Portrait Image ( 512 px x 640 px ) URL:**
`https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg`

and it looks like this.

[image: enter link description here]

**Low Resolution Portrait Image ( 256 px x 320 px ) URL:**
`https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg`

and it looks like this.

[image]

**Thumbnail Portrait Image ( 120 px x 150 px ) URL:**
`https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg`

and it looks like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: great! The tricky /c0.135.1080... doesn't have onto my image. https://instagram.com/p/654Dvup_k3

Comment: That string won't always be the same. So what you have to do is programatically , using `substring` functions or `regex`, remove the last but 1 segment of the image url from the square version to get the corresponding portrait or landscape version. I will take a look at your image via the api...

Comment: yeah, i tried something like that, but my image doesn't have that last segment.. https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11931019_1008201245898476_727940725_n.jpg

Comment: Your image doesn't have a last segment because it looks like it has been uploaded as a square image (there are white sections to left and right of the portrait photo). In other words, the original photo was a portrait, but when you uploaded it to instagram, it was made into a square photo and then uploaded.

Comment: Also instagram is rolling out this feature gradually, like they do for other major updates. Unless the version on your phone shows the landscape, portrait flip icon (as they showed in their blog post announcing this feature), all your photos and videos are going to be uploaded as square photos

Comment: @PedroCasado is right. Take a look: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11909381_778261432286393_1061732726_n.jpg (letterboxed) vs https://scontent-lga1-1.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg (original). You can see the original post here: https://instagram.com/p/7E-aDgNAY0/

Comment: @ArxPoetica I investigated the Portrait you have linked to. Strange in that the API returns 1 image name for Thumbnail, that has the last but 1 segment, and for other resolutions, it returns a different name. So I took the thumbnail, and removed the last but 1 segment and am able to get to the landscape version for all 3 sizes. See below....

Comment: (Thumbnail with last but 1 segment in url). `https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c236.0.608.608/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg` and here are the 3 size in landscape, uncropped.
Thumbnail: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg
Low Res: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg
Standard Res: https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e35/11821948_1196186947073869_307136947_n.jpg