# How do I get full-resolution images from Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

When I make a call to the endpoint

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

I get a response which includes this kind of thing:

```
{
...
   images: {
     low_resolution: { 
         url: "http://example.com/s320x320/oijwef/filename.jpg"
     },
     standard_resolution: { 
         url: "http://example.com/s640x640/23o8dn/filename.jpg"
     },
     thumbnail: { 
         url: "http://example.com/s150x150/20398x/filename.jpg"
     }
   }
}
```

The problem here is that even the standard resolution file is not the full image, and includes white bars in the image if the original is not a square.

Looking through their API docs, I don't see any way to get the original image path. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260896/instagram-square-photos-api

Comment: Thanks @PedroCasado, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the same problem discussed here: [Instagram Square photos API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260896/instagram-square-photos-api)

> **So How do you get the original image for a photo uploaded as a
>   landscape or portrait?**
>
> Since the API returns only 1 set of images as
>   of now, but the site is able to show the original aspect ratio images,
>   I did some digging around, and realized that if you remove the last
>   but 1 section of the url from the square image urls (in this example,
>   remove /c0.135.1080.1080 ) you get to the original aspect ratio sized
>   (and uncropped) landscape, portrait images.

Example:

```
"images": {
  "low_resolution": {
    "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
    "width": 320,
    "height": 320
  },
  "thumbnail": {
    "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
    "width": 150,
    "height": 150
  },
  "standard_resolution": {
    "url": "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/11909195_1715998838621946_791786043_n.jpg",
    "width": 640,
    "height": 640
  }
```

Comment: looks like Instagram are on to the trick and have shut it down (as of Jan 2018). Editing the URL in order to get a larger resolution image fails with 'invalid URL signature'